# How to connect online test LDAP server using vertx (java)

Tags: ldap, vert.x

I'm trying to connect the online test LDAP server and below is code i have tried.

```
      Vertx vertx = Vertx.vertx();
      JsonObject shiroConfig = new JsonObject().put("ldap_url", "ldap://ldap.forumsys.com:389")
        .put("ldap_user_dn_template", "uid={0},ou=mathematicians,dc=example,dc=com");
      ShiroAuthOptions shiroAuthOptions = new ShiroAuthOptions().setType(ShiroAuthRealmType.LDAP)
        .setConfig(shiroConfig);

      AuthProvider authProvider = ShiroAuth.create(vertx, shiroAuthOptions );

      JsonObject authInfo = new JsonObject().put("username", "reimann")
        .put("password", "password");

      System.out.println("before authenticate");
      authProvider.authenticate(authInfo, res -> {
        if (res.succeeded()) {
          System.out.println("Success");
        } else {
          System.out.println("failure" );
          System.out.println(res);
        }
      });
```

Below is the error i'm getting

```
before authenticate
failure
Future{cause=LDAP authentication failed.}
```

Below is the error, when res.cause().printStackTrace() was printed:

```
org.apache.shiro.authc.AuthenticationException: LDAP authentication failed.
    at org.apache.shiro.realm.ldap.DefaultLdapRealm.doGetAuthenticationInfo(DefaultLdapRealm.java:300)
    at org.apache.shiro.realm.AuthenticatingRealm.getAuthenticationInfo(AuthenticatingRealm.java:568)
    at org.apache.shiro.mgt.AuthenticatingSecurityManager.authenticate(AuthenticatingSecurityManager.java:106)
    at org.apache.shiro.mgt.DefaultSecurityManager.login(DefaultSecurityManager.java:270)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject.login(DelegatingSubject.java:256)
    at io.vertx.ext.auth.shiro.impl.ShiroAuthProviderImpl.lambda$authenticate$0(ShiroAuthProviderImpl.java:80)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextImpl.lambda$executeBlocking$2(ContextImpl.java:316)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.TaskQueue.run(TaskQueue.java:76)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.naming.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - Invalid Credentials]
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.mapErrorCode(LdapCtx.java:3135)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(LdapCtx.java:3081)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(LdapCtx.java:2883)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.connect(LdapCtx.java:2797)
    at org.apache.shiro.realm.ldap.JndiLdapContextFactory.getLdapContext(JndiLdapContextFactory.java:495)
    at org.apache.shiro.realm.ldap.DefaultLdapRealm.queryForAuthenticationInfo(DefaultLdapRealm.java:375)
    at org.apache.shiro.realm.ldap.DefaultLdapRealm.doGetAuthenticationInfo(DefaultLdapRealm.java:295)
    ... 14 more
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

With vert.x 4.0 to be released soon, Shiro will be marked as Deprecated and you're kindly asked to move to `vertx-auth-ldap`. The difference is that this new module will only use the JDK classes. Shiro is deprecated because it does not work correctly with the asynchronous model (it relies on thread locals, and we had to hack it's internals to work as expected).

With the new module you can connect to a ldap server as:

```
LdapAuthenticationOptions ldapOptions = 
  new LdapAuthenticationOptions()
    .setUrl("ldap://localhost:port")
    .setAuthenticationQuery("uid={0},ou=Users,dc=myorg,dc=com");
```

From here is you need custom customization, just follow the official java tutorial trail: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jndi/tutorial/ldap/security/ldap.html

Here's the module documentation: https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-auth/blob/master/vertx-auth-ldap/src/main/asciidoc/index.adoc

Comment: I will use the same whatever you have suggested. But wanted to know the problem with the code i shared. Why am i getting error?

Comment: I'm not a Shiro expert (or LDAP for the sake of it), but if you do `res.cause().printStackTrace()` will it give you some hint?

Comment: i have edited the question printing the error lines after after adding res.cause().printStackTrace()  in code

Comment: Online test LDAP server - [link](https://www.forumsys.com/tutorials/integration-how-to/ldap/online-ldap-test-server/)

Comment: Yeah. But credentials shared in Online LDAP test server is the same. Unable to understand, where am i going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I hope it's not too late. I solved it in the following way:

```
LdapAuthenticationOptions ldapOptions =
                new LdapAuthenticationOptions()
                        .setUrl("ldap://ldap.forumsys.com:389")
                        .setAuthenticationQuery("uid={0},dc=example,dc=com");
        LdapAuthentication ldapAuthentication = LdapAuthentication.create(Vertx.currentContext().owner(), ldapOptions);
        Future<User> future = ldapAuthentication.authenticate(new JsonObject().put("username", "newton")
                        .put("password", "password"));
```